# Setting panel-objects properties

Tags: c#, inheritance, panels

I'm making a Windows Form Application called FMP.
I've got a class called Form1, a class called Panels.
Then I use inheritance to make different Panels with different properties.

The reason for doing this is because the teacher doesn't want us to initialize all the panels in the Form-class.

But I'm not sure how to do this. Found some things here @Stackoverflow, but they couldn't help me either.

The Size, The Location and the color are for all the Panels the same. (By clicking on a button, an other panel will appear ;) )
But the Name, Controls on the panel, and BackgroundImages are different. The controls are the most important aspect here.

The question is:

The Width and the Height should be equal to the Widht and the Height from the Form.
What is best in programming C#? To set the Width and the Height from Panels in the Form1 (but i made them protected) or declarate the form in the Panels class and use
Form1.Width?

The code I'm having right know:

The Form1

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonsProperties();
        panelsProperties();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelsChanged(1);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelsChanged(2);
    }
    private void panelsChanged(int panelNr)
    {
        if (panelNr == 1)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel1.Enabled = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel2.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (panelNr == 2)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel1.Enabled = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
            panel2.Enabled = true;
        }
}
```

The Panels

```
class Panels
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    //Color Property
    protected Color color { get; set; }
    //Size
    protected Int32 Width { get; set; }
    protected Int32 Height{ get; set; }
    //Location
    protected Point Location { get; set; }
    public Panels()
    {
        initMembers();
    }

    private void initMembers()
    {
        this.Width = f.Width;
        this.Height = f.Height;
        this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }
}
public class Panel1 : Panels
{
    //Nothing yet.
}
```

Comment: If the panels are supposed to fill the entire form area, you may want to try `panel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`.

Comment: Thank you the DockStyle.Fill is an option. But the program doesn't draw the panel. I think it is beacause I can't add it to the 
Form1.Controls (    this.Controls.Add(panels) //Error    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the name `Panels` as a base class for each panel is confusing:

- The name should not be in a plural form, as each instance of the class clearly resembles one "panel" (a *panel* has a Width, multiple *panels* do not have (one) width)
- Since you're crating a WinForms application, the name looks too much like the `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` class

If I were you I'd let *your* base class derive from `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`:

```
abstract class MyPanelBase : Panel
{
    public MyPanelBase()
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
}

class MyPanel1 : MyPanelBase
{
}
```

This way you automatically get the behavior (and properties) of the `Panel` and it allows you to add it to a parent control (in your case, the form).

If all functionality you want is already supported by `Panel` you could even skip the `MyPanelBase` bit and let `MyPanel1` derive directly from `Panel`.

Comment: Thank you, that should help, I gues :). But my panels have all the same size. They're only not visible at the same time.

Comment: @E.Verdi you could set that size (or the `Dock` property) in the `MyPanelBase` constructor if you go for that solution.